# Capture SQL 2014 installation errors

Tags: sql-server, powershell, windows-server

Right now when I install SQL 2014 (via a PowerShell script) it automatically sends errors to:

> c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup
>   Bootstrap\Log\blahblahlog.txt

I'm hoping to capture those errors. I have a custom error log that captures other things throughout my PowerShell script. I'm trying to find a starting point, or if this is even possible. The errors logged there are very specific and useful to me.

An obvious solution is to just grab the contents of that log file, but I'm hoping to cut out the middle man.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28126861/1703778)?

Comment: @TomV Good idea, but I am already running the extracted .exe file. That is interesting though. So the .exe is going to have some kind of "standardoutput" that I can call in PowerShell, and grab text from it?

Comment: I know the CU and SP give you the option to `/INDICATEPROGRESS` this option has the info written to the log file to output on the screen.